# Changing a Custom Range Function to a Custom Array Function

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, function

I created the below function to calculate the average distance travelled on a 37 tooth wheel, I'm happy with it and it works fine, but it calculates on a range, so it means I have to have the figures placed into a set range and calculate it from there.

```
Public Function AVGDISTCALC(rng As Range)
'Determines the average distance of a number of distances on a 37 tooth wheel.
Dim x As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim avg As Integer
Dim diff As Integer
Dim arr() As Variant
Dim R As Long
Dim c As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Write the range to an array.
    arr = rng
    'Cycle through each increment on the 37 tooth wheel.
    diff = 38
    For i = 1 To 37
    arr = rng
        'For each increment calculate the min and max of the range.
        For R = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
            For c = 1 To UBound(arr, 2)
                If (arr(R, c) + i) Mod 37 = 0 Then
                    arr(R, c) = 37
                Else
                    arr(R, c) = (arr(R, c) + i) Mod 37
                End If
            Next c
        Next R
        If WorksheetFunction.Max(arr) - WorksheetFunction.Min(arr) < diff Then
            diff = WorksheetFunction.Max(arr) - WorksheetFunction.Min(arr)
            avg = WorksheetFunction.Average(arr)
            x = i
        End If
    Next i
    
    Select Case avg - x
    Case 0
        AVGDISTCALC = 37
    Case Is > 0
        AVGDISTCALC = avg - x
    Case Is < 0
        AVGDISTCALC = (avg - x) + 37
    End Select
    
End Function
```

Writing to the range uses memory and costs speed obviously, so I thought I would change the function to accept an array... Now in my stupidity I thought it would just be a case of using Paramarray to set the new variable, but it isn't because it keeps coming up with errors so I try something new. Ive had wrong number of dimensions error and before this I had another error, I forget what now. Am I just being stupid or missing something, I just thought it would work just as the range function. Please help. Thanking you all in advance.

```
Public Function AVGDISTCALCarr(ParamArray arr1() As Variant)
'Determines the average distance of a number of distances on a 37 tooth wheel.
Dim x As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim avg As Integer
Dim diff As Integer
Dim R As Long
Dim c As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Cycle through each increment on the 37 tooth wheel.
    diff = 38
    For i = 1 To 37
        'For each increment calculate the min and max of the range.
        For R = 1 To UBound(arr1, 1)
            For c = 1 To UBound(arr1, 2)
                If (arr1(R, c) + i) Mod 37 = 0 Then
                    arr1(R, c) = 37
                Else
                    arr1(R, c) = (arr1(R, c) + i) Mod 37
                End If
            Next c
        Next R
        If WorksheetFunction.Max(arr1) - WorksheetFunction.Min(arr1) < diff Then
            diff = WorksheetFunction.Max(arr1) - WorksheetFunction.Min(arr1)
            avg = WorksheetFunction.Average(arr1)
            x = i
        End If
    Next i
    
    Select Case avg - x
    Case 0
        AVGDISTCALCarr = 37
    Case Is > 0
        AVGDISTCALCarr = avg - x
    Case Is < 0
        AVGDISTCALCarr = (avg - x) + 37
    End Select
    
End Function
```

I'm running a macro that churns out various distances on the cog. I then write these to a worksheet so that I can perform the function (the range version) I then take this average distance calculated and continue running the macro. So I am trying to remove the writing to the worksheet and just calculate it as an array.
Here is an example of the type of array I am creating...

```
Sub MultiSector()

Dim Closearr(1 To 3) As Integer
Dim Closeaverage As Integer

Closearr(1) = 11
Closearr(2) = 22
Closearr(3) = 33
Closeaverage = AVGDISTCALCarr(Closearr)

End Sub
```

But fiddling around I'm either getting number of dimensions errors or it doesn't like the argument in AVGDISTCALCarr(Closearr), which I don't get, surely I just put the array name in? Hope this explains better.

Comment: You should [edit] and tag a language. [tag:vba]? [tag:excel]?

Comment: You've left out the Function header, which is critical to this Q.  Please edit it in

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I've acted on those two suggestions.

Comment: At first glance, just remove `ParamArray`. Are you saying that at the moment you have a procedure that somehow generates some values in an array and its values are written to a range, then you use this procedure to write the values from the range into an array to calculate the average, or is there something else going on?

Comment: Hi VBasic2008, sorry for my lack of technical knowledge on the jargon side but I have added to the end of the text hoping that this explains my problems more clearly. Thanks for your time.

Comment: The problem is that `Closearr` is a 1D one-based array, while the function expects a 2D one-based array. You could solve this easily by removing the inner `c` loop (`For c...` and `Next c`) and the 4 occurrences of `, c` (making the array 1D: `arr1(R)`). If you have a code for how you previously wrote the values to the range, I'd be glad to adjust this set-up for you. A possible simplification with `Dim CloseArr(): CloseArr = Array(11, 22, 33, 44, 55)` would be possible, when additionally, you would need to change to `For R = LBound(arr1) To UBound(arr1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Passing an Array to a Procedure

**The Calling Procedure**

```
Sub MultiSector()

    Dim CloseArr(): CloseArr = Array( _
        11, 22, 33, _
        44, 55, 66) ' add as many as necessary
    Dim CloseAverage As Long: CloseAverage = GetAvgDistance(CloseArr)

End Sub
```

**The Function**

```
Function GetAvgDistance(ByVal Arr As Variant) As Long
'Determines the average distance of a number of distances on a 37 tooth wheel.
    
    ' Declare whole number variables as Long, decimals as Double,
    ' and arrays as Variant.
    ' Your data is far too small to complicate things.

    Dim x As Long, i As Long, r As Long,avg As Long, diff As Long
    
    'Cycle through each increment on the 37-tooth wheel.
    diff = 38
    For i = 1 To 37
        'For each increment calculate the min and max of the range.
        For r = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr) ' 1D
            If (Arr(r) + i) Mod 37 = 0 Then
                Arr(r) = 37
            Else
                Arr(r) = (Arr(r) + i) Mod 37
            End If
        Next r
        ' Introduce the With statement to make it more readable.
        With WorksheetFunction
            If .Max(Arr) - .Min(Arr) < diff Then
                diff = .Max(Arr) - .Min(Arr)
                avg = .Average(Arr)
                x = i
            End If
        End With
    Next i
    
    Select Case avg - x
        Case 0: GetAvgDistance = 37
        Case Is > 0: GetAvgDistance = avg - x
        Case Is < 0: GetAvgDistance = avg - x + 37
    End Select
    
End Function
```

Comment: This is perfect VBasic2008. I had given a go at trying to rectify my function after your last advice and I nearly got there. Your writing is so much more neater and concise though. Thank you! :-)